# Unable to terminate forked process

Tags: c, linux, gpio

I have a process which has to be terminated using Ctrl-C or SIGINT. In this case I cannot use Ctrl-C physically with the keyboard, so it has to done using a kill command in C. 
This code basically reads GPIO input and starts and stops a script record.sh , a GStreamer command line script.

I only want to terminate the child process created in startVideoRecording(). I need to do start, stop, start, stop the recording as many times as I like. It's not a one-off thing.

However, when I change the gpio value and trigger stopAllRecordings(), it doesn't send the SIGINT to the child process. It just hangs there at "Sending interrupt to GStreamer process.. Status 0"

How can I make sure that the video recording process is terminated with a Ctrl-C equivalent?

Thanks.

Here's the code :

```
int main() {
    pollGPIOSwitch(&vn200);
}


void* pollGPIOSwitch(void* arg) {


   Vn200* vn200 = (Vn200*)arg;
   int fd;
   char buf[100];
   char value; 
   int videoRecError;
   bool videoRecOn = false;

   sprintf(buf, "/sys/class/gpio/gpio56/value");

   while (KEEP_GOING) {
       fd = open(buf,O_RDONLY);
       lseek(fd,0,SEEK_SET); // move to beginning of file
       read(fd,&value,1);
       if (value=='0') {
           if (videoRecOn) { // recording on, switch off, end recording
               stopAllRecordings();
               videoRecOn = false;
               TriggerGPSINSThreadExit = 0; // reset variables
               printf("Reset GPSINS Thread variables.\n");
           }
       }
       else if (!videoRecOn) { // recording off, switch on, start recording
            if (pthread_create(&GPSINSLoggingThread, NULL, runGPSINS,(void*) vn200) != 0) {
                printf("Error: Fail to create runGPSINS thread\n");
            }

            videoRecError = startVideoRecording();
            if (videoRecError == -1)
                pthread_exit(&videoRecError);
            videoRecOn = true; 
       }
       usleep(500000);
   }
   close(fd);


   printf("Exited Polling!");
}

int startVideoRecording() {
    int error;
    error = 0;

    if ((AVRecordingProcess = fork()) != -1) {
        switch (AVRecordingProcess) {
            case -1:
                printf("Error: Fail to create AVRecordingProcess\n");
                error = -1;
            case 0:
                execl("record.sh", "0", NULL);
                //system("//root//record.sh");
                printf("Error: Fail to execute AVRecordingProcess\n");
                error = -1;
            default:
               printf("Video Recording...process id %d\n", AVRecordingProcess); 
                break;
        }
    } else {  
        printf("Error: MainHost failed to fork AVRecordingProcess\n");
        error = -1;
    } 

    return error;

}


void stopAllRecordings() {
    int ret; 
    FILE *infile, *outfile;
    int ch;


    printf("Terminating child processes..%d\n", AVRecordingProcess);
    ret = kill(AVRecordingProcess, SIGINT);
    printf("Sending interrupt to GStreamer process.. Status %d\n", ret);

    int status;
    printf("Wait for the GStreamer process %d to end....", AVRecordingProcess);
    wait(AVRecordingProcess);
    printf("GStreamer ended.\n"); 
}
```

Comment: You are crating a new thread every time the recording is off and you need to start it. Your thread function is runGPSINS. What is the function definition? And again you are forking in startVideoRecording() function just after creating thread? If the child process starts the recording, what is the thread for?

Comment: Sorry pls ignore that, there's some other function where I terminate the thread.

Comment: @Ippier, theres other irrelevant crud in the code you pasted. Makes it hard to read quickly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually did this :

```
int startVideoRecording() {
    int error;
    error = 0;

    if ((AVRecordingProcess = fork()) != -1) {
        switch (AVRecordingProcess) {
            case -1:
                printf("Error: Fail to create AVRecordingProcess\n");
                error = -1;
            case 0:
                setpgid(AVRecordingProcess,0);  <-- NEW
                execl("record.sh", "0", NULL);
                //system("//root//record.sh");
                printf("Error: Fail to execute AVRecordingProcess\n");
                error = -1;
            default:
               printf("Video Recording...process id %d\n", AVRecordingProcess); 
                break;
        }
    } else {  
        printf("Error: MainHost failed to fork AVRecordingProcess\n");
        error = -1;
    } 

    return error;

}

void stopAllRecordings() {
    int ret; 
    FILE *infile, *outfile;
    int ch;


    printf("Terminating child processes..%d\n", AVRecordingProcess);
    ret = killpg(AVRecordingProcess, SIGINT); <-- NEW
    printf("Sending interrupt to GStreamer process.. Status %d\n", ret);

    int status;
    printf("Wait for the GStreamer process %d to end....", AVRecordingProcess);
    waitpid(AVRecordingProcess,0,0); <-- NEW
    printf("GStreamer ended.\n"); 
}
```

and it works.

Basically, during the creation of the AVRecordingProcess, I set it as the head of the process group. 
Sending the process group SIGINT sends it also to the rest of the processes within the group. 
To make sure the process group ended, I used waitpid.

Linux experts, feel free to correct me, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that you are starting multiple child processes and only sending SIGINT to the last child process you created and not earlier ones?  Type 'PS' and hit enter after starting this program and see how many processes you have started.

Comment: Hi @Nick Wilkerson, I see this after I start the recording. 28782 - HRS (my main program) 28921 - record.sh (my script) 28922 - gst-launch-0.10 (the gstreamer command line). How do I send a SIGINT to gst-launch-0.10 in my case? I'm guessing maybe it didn't get the SIGINT?

Comment: The way you are using kill is correct.  It is possible, although unlikely that your child process is ignoring SIGINT.  You could try SIGKILL.

Comment: Try setting the process group id of all of your child processes to the same process group id and then send your sigint or sigkill to that process group id instead of the individual process ids.